# Quartz Cron Expressions Issues

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Hi I am very new to the "Quartz Scheduler". I have a cron expression like

"0 0 0/24 * * ?" -- Which means every the task will execute every 24 hours. Is it right?

If it is yes, when the schedule will start. For example If I start my server at 10AM is the scheduler will execute 10AM everyday.

My task is I want to schedule a task on every day.

Can any one help on this...?

Thanq,
Amar.

Comment: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Comment: My question is is it okay If I use "0/24" in hours place. If it's yes what is it meant by is it execute when I start a server or is it execute 00:00AM ? Please clarify me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> / - used to specify increments. For example, "0/15" in the seconds field means "the seconds 0, 15, 30, and 45". And "5/15" in the seconds field means "the seconds 5, 20, 35, and 50". You can also specify '/' after the '' character - in this case '' is equivalent to having '0' before the '/'. '1/3' in the day-of-month field means "fire every 3 days starting on the first day of the month".

Check the below cron

> 0 0 12 1/1 * ? *

The above expression will trigger daily at 12 PM. You can use the following site to generate your cron expressions. http://www.cronmaker.com/

Also your cron expression has interval of 24 hours which mean that it would trigger every day. The expression 0/24 means that even if you started at 10:00 AM it will trigger next day at 12:00 AM. Also if you want it to trigger daily instead of having the interval of 24 hours use 1/1 in day part.

AFAIK The scheduler does not handle interval based on server start time. Interval is calculated based on last trigger time.

Comment: Hay Thanq Pratik. It clarified my doubts.